# org.threeten.bp zonedDateTime.parse does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, zoneddatetime, threetenbp

Hi I am trying to use org.threeten.bp library and format a date string to zonnedDateTime but it does not work.

```
   val dateFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val aOne = ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-08-11", dateFormatter)
```

I am using import org.threeten.bp.* library.

error I get is

`org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-08-11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: DateTimeBuilder[, ISO, null, 2022-08-11, null], type org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeBuilder`

could you suggest what I am doing wrong here please

Thanks
R

Comment: what happens if you turn it into a localdate? You don't have time and zoneinformation. makes sense that it cannot construct a zoneddatetime from it.

Comment: Tip of the day: paste your error message into your search engine. First remove any parts that are specific to the data you use like `'2022-08-11'`.

Comment: It would immediately seem that @DanielJacob is correct, a `LocalDate` would fit your data better. Have you got a reason for needing a `ZonedDateTime`? If so, what time zone and what time of day do you want? Sure it’s possible.